# Was Muhammad asked the exact date for Laylat al-Qadr (night of decree)?

Tags: ramadan, laylat-al-qadr

Was prophet Muhammad (pbuh) ever asked about the exact date of "[Laylat al-Qadr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laylat_al-Qadr)" (the night of decree during [Ramadan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramadan)) and if so, what was his answer?

> Indeed, We sent the Qur'an down during the Night of Decree. 97:1
>   And what can make you know what is the Night of Decree? 97:2
>   The Night of Decree is better than a thousand months. 97:3

Answer (score 2):

According to Shi'a Islam, the Prophet (SAWW) did not specify the exact date of Laylatul-Qadr (night of decree), but there is a narration from the Prophet (s) which could be related with your question, so it has narrated that:

> A person told Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) my house is far from Medina,,
>   tell me the Laylatul-Qadr, the Prophet (SAWW) responded: come on 23th.
>
> «وَ فِی رِوَایَةِ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ بُکَیْرٍ عَنْ زُرَارَةَ عَنْ
>   أَحَدِهِمَا(ع) قَالَ سَأَلْتُهُ عَنِ اللَّیَالِی الَّتِی یُسْتَحَبُّ
>   فِیهَا الْغُسْلُ فِی شَهْرِ رَمَضَانَ فَقَالَ لَیْلَةُ تِسْعَ عَشْرَةَ
>   وَ لَیْلَةُ إِحْدَى وَ عِشْرِینَ وَ لَیْلَةُ ثَلَاثٍ وَ عِشْرِینَ وَ
>   قَالَ لَیْلَةُ ثَلَاثٍ وَ عِشْرِینَ هِیَ لَیْلَةُ الْجُهَنِیِّ وَ
>   حَدِیثُهُ أَنَّهُ قَالَ لِرَسُولِ اللَّهِ ص إِنَّ مَنْزِلِی نَاءٍ عَنِ
>   الْمَدِینَةِ فَمُرْنِی بِلَیْلَةٍ أَدْخُلُ فِیهَا فَأَمَرَهُ
>   بِلَیْلَةِ ثَلَاثٍ وَ عِشْرِینَ»؛ من لا یحضره الفقیه، ج 2، ص 160 –
>   161.
>
> (Man La Yahzarah al Faqih Vol.2, Pages 160-161)

In accordance with the majority of the Shia scholars view (according to some traditions), the night of decree or Laylatul-Qadr is probably one of the following days of Ramadan:

> 19th, 21st, 23rd .

Imam Aboo Ja’far Muhammad ebn Ali-al-Baqir (a.s.) is quoted in Bihar al-Anwar and Da’aim al-Islam as mentioned:

> "The 17th night of the month of Ramadhan is when the 2 parties met,
>
> and the 19th is at the time that the lists of the pilgrims is written
>   down,
>
> and the 21st is at the time that successors to the Prophets passed
>   away and Jesus Christ (as) was raised to heaven and Moses (as) passed
>   away,
>
> whereas the 23rd is hoped to be Lailatul-Qadr."

---

**Source(s):**

[www.al-islam.org](http://www.al-islam.org/fast-month-ramadhan-philosophy-and-ahkam-yasin-t-al-jibouri/which-night-lailatul-qadr)

[www.askdin.com](http://www.askdin.com/thread7366.html)

[www.islamquest.net](http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa34864)

Answer (score 0):

No one knows about the exact date of laylatul Qadr because according to hadith, in last 5 days (that is 21st, 23rd, 25th, 27th and 29th) dates of Ramadan are generally called night of laylatul Qadr and we have to pray all the nights in these dates because Except Allah no one knows that which night is laylatul Qadr night but it is sure that in these five nights one night will be laylatul Qadr, That's why everyone prays on these nights.

Allah knows better

Comment: According to which hadith exactly?

Comment: Our prophet (S.A.W) use to pray in these nights means last ten days of Ramadan and specially 5 odd numbers of last days.

Comment: Your doubt will be more clear by reading this, click on this link and you will find your all answer related to laylatul Qadr but its request to you that read till last www.qss.org/articles/ramadan/8.html

Answer (score 0):

The Prophet (PBUH) did get asked; his answer was about to be said, apparently, when suddenly a sound, thing or person broke their conversation (Muhammad -S.A's- and the person who asked him's), and that's what I heard and read. We have to observe in the last 10 days (or 5?) of the Holy Month of Ramadan, the odd dates, for Laylatul-Qadr.

Allah is Oneness.
Obey Allah, for the sake of Mankind.